# Limit decimals of mean in groupby Python

Tags: python, pandas, rounding, mean

I've got this Python code (has to do with a car db). I want to you use round to limit the number of decimals, but can't figure out what the right code should be. I understand the round function, but I just can't figure it out in combination with `mean()`.

```
grouped_test_bodystyle = df_gptest2.groupby(['body-style'],as_index= False).mean()
```

The result is of course this, where I want to limit price to two decimals.

```
     body-style     price
  0  convertible    21890.500000
  1  hardtop    22208.500000
  2  hatchback  9957.441176
  3  sedan  14459.755319
  4  wagon  12371.960000
```

Does anyone know how to get '`round`' in this part of code:

```
.....as_index= False).mean().
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataFrame.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) after doing `groupby`

```
df_gptest2.groupby(['body-style'],as_index= False).mean().round(2)
Out[4]: 
    body-style     price
0  convertible  21890.50
1      hardtop  22208.50
2    hatchback   9957.44
3        sedan  14459.76
4        wagon  12371.96
```